# Find $\lim _{ n\to\infty}\sum _{k=1}^{n}\frac{\sqrt{k}}{{n}^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Need help computing: $\displaystyle\lim _{n\to\infty}\sum _{k=1}^{n}\frac{\sqrt{k}}{{n}^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

Now my intuition is that using Stolz-Cesaro

$\displaystyle\lim _{n\to\infty}\sum _{k=1}^n\frac{\sqrt{k}}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\lim _{ n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum _{k=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{k}{n}}=1$

Is it correct or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about using Riemann sums??
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt k}{n^{3/2}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{\frac k n} = \int_0^1 \sqrt x dx $$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Rewrite as 
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_1^n \sqrt{\frac{k}{n}},$$
 and recognize it as a Riemann sum. The limit is not $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Applying Cesaro-Stolz theorem, the solution of the problem is:
$$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }{ \frac { \sqrt { k }  }{ { n }^{ \frac { 3 }{ 2 }  } }  }  } = \lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{(n+1)\sqrt{n+1}-n\sqrt{n}}=\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }\frac{\sqrt{n+1}[(n+1)\sqrt{n+1}+n\sqrt{n}]}{(n+1)^3-n^3}=$$$$=\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }\frac{(n+1)^2+n\sqrt{n(n+1)}}{3n^2+3n+1}=\frac{2}{3}$$