# Limit of finite Sum

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n} \sqrt{\frac{i}{n}}\right)$$Any tips how to solve this problem, because clearly I have no idea how to approach it.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469885/the-limit-of-a-sum-sum-k-1n-fracnn2k2?lq=1 OR  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465075/find-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac1n-sum-limits2n-r-1-fracr-sq

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805693/find-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sum-k-1-n-frac-sqrt-k?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** This is a Riemann Sum

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum _{i=0}^{n} \sqrt{\frac{i}{n}} = \int_0^1 \sqrt x\, dx =\frac{2}{3}.$$